# Node is not able to connect to Hub, keep sending registration event

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-cloudformation, selenium-grid

**Objective:** UI test execution takes quite a time and we have a lot of UI test cases, currently we have a grid setup on AWS EC2 but scaling and descaling of resources manualy is time-consuming, so we decided to explore AWS ECS Fargate where we can scale based on CPU and Memory utilization.
Motivation blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/run-selenium-tests-at-scale-using-aws-fargate/

**Problem Statement:** Node is initiating registration requests but it is not able to register itself to the hub.

**Findings till now:** I found a [repo](https://github.com/taktakpeops/selenium-grid-ecs-fargate) on git which is doing what we are trying to achieve except for one thing, that is in version **3.141.59** and we want the version **4.4.0-20220831**

**What I can achieve:** So using this repo I changed the version of Hub and Node to 4.4.0-20220831 and also changed environment variables according to the specific version requirements, on the execution of cloudFormation template Hub is up and running but there was no node connected when I checked the log of hub and node, I found hub service was configured and running as well as the node service was sending registration requests for N times.

This is my first question here so I am not able to show images in question itself, sorry for inconveniance.

**HUB Screenshots**

- [Hub environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8cTJ.png)
- [Hub service discovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHWjE.png)
- [Hub logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn29L.png)

**Node Screenshots**

- [Node environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhZex.png)
- [Node service discovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zfcq.png)
- [Node logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmF5R.png)

Before changing anything everyting is working as expected on V3 but we need V4.
Thank you for gving your valuable time, looking forward for you response.
Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with any of these resources, when I allowed ports 4442 and 4443 in my security group it worked.

Thank you everyone for your time and support.